# Node request module works on local hosting but returns 'Unhandled stream error in pipe' in Heroku,

Tags: node.js, heroku, stream, fs, node-request

I'm using node request module to upload external files to the server. It works perfectly well when I test it locally, but when uploaded to heroku. I get this error whenever I try to upload an image..

internal/streams/legacy.js:57
throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.

Here's my code...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var path = require('path');

function downloadRemote(url, dest, filename, cb) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest + "/" + filename + path.extname(url));

    request.get(url, function(err, resp, body){
        if(err){
            console.log(err.message, ' file deleted');
            file.close();
            fs.unlinkSync(dest + "/" + filename + path.extname(url));
        } else {
            file.on('finish', function() {
                file.close(cb);
            });
        }
    })
    .pipe(file);
}

var url = 'external link here'
downloadRemote(url, 'downloadedAssets/imgs', 'spongebob, function(){
//call back function
}
```

Any ideas why I keep getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

you change calling your function and pass a string fileName:

'spongebob to 'spongebob' in this code

```
var url = 'external link here'
downloadRemote(url, 'downloadedAssets/imgs', 'spongebob', function(){
//call back function
}
```